# Как в списке списков удалить элементы с повторяющимся вложенным элементом?

Tags: python, list

Есть список списков

```
lst = [[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7], [6, 8], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12]]
```

Мне нужно убрать из списка список, где повторяется одно из значений в другом списке. т.е. получить

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 7], [6, 8], [9, 11], [10, 12]]
```

Пробую через not in, append

```
def correct_lst(lst):
    lst1 = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[0])):
            if lst[i][j] not in lst1:
                lst1.append(lst[i])
    return lst1
```

так тоже не выходит:

```
def correct_lst(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i][1] == lst[i + 2][0]:
            del lst[i+2]
        return lst
```

Что не так?

Comment: При таком подходе вам надо делать еще один цикл по вложенным циклам. или делайте  временный список с добавленными элементами

Comment: А каким образом в ваш результирующий список попал элемент - например [1,3], если тройка повторяется и в элементе [3, 5] ????

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать временный сетс добавленными элементами

```
lst1 = []
tmp = set()
for x in lst:
    if all(map(lambda x: x not in tmp, x)):
        lst1.append(x)
        tmp |= set(x)
print(lst1)
print(tmp)
```

Comment: Если уж через множества, то и проверку делать через них же: `if not set(x) & tmp:`. Однообразие лучше, чем разнообразие внутри одной функции.

Comment: Кстати, интересный вопрос, что дороже - not in или пересечение с созданием еще одного множества. Я не уверен

Comment: Так навскидку я не поручусь, нужно мерить. По скорости да, ваш вариант всё же наверное лучше. Просто не люблю код когда там зоопарк методик.

Comment: @CrazyElf ваше мнение имеет право на жизнь, но not in - вполне универсальная комструкция языка, которая не ориентирована специально на список, кортеж ...

Comment: Да я даже не про `in`, он прекрасен, конечно, а про `map` и `lambda` )

Comment: Да конечно, затупил

Answer (score 0):

По моему, ТС явно ошибся в вопросе.
Если исходить из того, что `"нужно убрать из списка список, где повторяется одно из значений в другом списке"` то ни один из элементов начального списка не должен попасть в результат. В приведенной  примере ТС говорит:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 7], [6, 8], [9, 11], [10, 12]]
```

вот только тройка, четверка, пятерка, шестерка, семерка, восьмерка, девятка и десятка в исходном списке

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7], [6, 8], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12]]
```

**встречаются более одного раза.** Что противоречит условию.

А вот если взять начальный список, например, вот такой

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4],  [4, 6], [5, 7], [6, 8],  [9, 11], [10, 12]]
```

то вот тогда результат должен быть

```
[[1, 3], [5, 7], [9, 11], [10, 12]]
```

И чтобы добиться такого (правильного) результата, мы можем использовать указанное свойство. По разному использовать, например, вот так:

```
flt_lst=[item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
lst1=[]
for itm in lst:
    if flt_lst.count(itm[0])==1 & flt_lst.count(itm[1])==1:
        lst1.append(itm)
```

Comment: Судя по всему автор вопроса имел в виду исключение *повторных* элементов, а не *повторяющихся* )

Comment: Не-а. Тогда почему в его примере-ответе  осталось [5, 7].  Дело в том, что в  исходном списке есть ранее встретившийся элемент [3, 5]. Выходит, что  5 -  "повторный" элемент элемент.  А из списка убрано именно первое (а не повторное) появление этого элемента. У меня такое впечатление, что ТС сам не понимает, что и почему написал.